# I'm trying to remove all prime numbers from an arraylist, but nothing is printing?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a bit of a newbie, so I apologize for any silly errors.

Here's the code:

```
    public static void keepOnlyCompositeNumbers( List<Integer> nums ){

    int num=0;
    boolean isPrime=true;
    for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++){
        num=nums.get(i);
        {
            for (int o = 2; o < num; ++i)
            {
                if (num % o == 0){
                    isPrime=false;
                    o=2;        
                    if(isPrime==true){
                                nums.remove(num);
                            }
                }


            }


}
```

And the runner class:

```
    Integer[] nums = {2,6,8,9,10,12,13,15,17,24,55,66,78,77,79};
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>( Arrays.asList(nums) );

    System.out.println( list );
    ArrayListFunHouse.keepOnlyCompositeNumbers( list );
    System.out.println( list );
```

Nothing's printing. Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong, please? I have been stumped for quite some time. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This can can never work `isPrime=false;
                    num=2;      
                    if(isPrime==true){
                                nums.remove(num);
                            }`

Comment: The condition you are using to check a prime number is wrong

Comment: Silly to use an ArrayList for this. Make your life easier, use an array of booleans.

Comment: I'm really kind of frustrated at most of the answers to this question.  The questioner has made some mistakes in his code, and we have an opportunity to help him see what his mistakes are so that he can avoid them in the future.  Instead, most everyone here would rather show off that they know how to write the code better.  Congratulations.  But not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
public static void keepOnlyCompositeNumbers( List<Integer> nums ){
  boolean isPrime=false;
  for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++){
  isPrime = checkPrime(nums.get(i));
    if(isPrime){
        nums.remove(i);
    }
  System.out.println(nums);
}
boolean checkPrime(int n) {
        for(int i=2;i<n;i++) {
            if(n%i==0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
}
```

Fetch each number in for loop and check in separate method for prime if return value is true which is prime number than remove it.

You'r not getting output because of infinite loop

```
for (int o = 2; o < num; ++i)
```

problem is you are increment i instead of o, and loop will get infinite when it get input which is greater than 2

Comment: "_Nothing's printing. Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?_" This doesn't explain why OP's code was not outputting anything.

Answer (score 1):

More efficent checkPrime

```
boolean checkPrime(int n) {
        for(int i=2;i<=n/2;i++) {
            if(n%i==0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
}
```

Comment: "_Nothing's printing. Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?_" This doesn't explain why OP's code was not outputting anything.

Comment: Why n/2? And why not make use of the list of primes you've already accumulated?

Comment: Nedd not to check from 2 to n, we can check it 2 to n/2

Comment: But why n/2, when you only need to check up to sqrt(n)? (if pq = n, then at least one of p, q is less than or equal to the square root of n)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Integer[] nums = { 2, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 15, 17, 24, 55, 66, 78, 77, 79 };
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(nums));

        System.out.println("Original List => " + list);
        keepOnlyCompositeNumbers(list);
        System.out.println("FInal List => " + list);
    }

    public static void keepOnlyCompositeNumbers(List<Integer> nums) {

        for (int i = 0 ; i < nums.size() ; i++) {
            if (isPrime(nums.get(i))) {
                nums.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int number) {
        for (int i = 2 ; i < number ; i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                return false; // number is divisible so its not prime
            }
        }
        return true; // number is prime now
    }
```

**output**

> Original List => [2, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 15, 17, 24, 55, 66, 78, 77,
>   79]
>
> FInal List => [6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 24, 55, 66, 78, 77]

Answer (score 0):

Working from Sarz's answer, something like this should work a little better for checkPrimes:

```
public static void keepOnlyCompositeNumbers( List<Integer> nums ){
  boolean isPrime=false;
  for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++){
  if ( checkPrime(nums.get(i), nums)) 
        nums.remove(i);
}
boolean checkPrime(int n, List <Integer> primes) {
    sqrtn = Math.sqrt(n) ;
    for (Integer p : primes) {
        if (p > sqrtn) 
             return true;
        if (n % p == 0)
             return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of mistakes here.  There may be others.

```
   num=nums.get(i);
    {
        for (int o = 2; o < num; ++i)
        {
            if (num % o == 0){
                isPrime=false;
                o=2;        
                if(isPrime==true){
                            nums.remove(num);
                        }
            }


        }
```

1)  `for (int o = 2; o < num; ++i)` seems like a typo.  The loop will exit when `o` becomes `num` or greater.  But you're not incrementing `o`, you're incrementing `i`.  Understandable since they're right next to each other on the keyboard, and the compiler didn't catch it since `i` exists as a variable.

2)  Even if you change it to `o++`, you sabotage your loop by setting `o=2` if the number is non-prime.  This means that `o < num` will never be true, because you keep setting it back to 2, and the loop will go on forever.

It appears that you're trying to say "this number is composite, so let's go to the next number".  But you're not.  `nums.remove(num)` removes `num` from the list, **but it does not change num**.  You haven't done anything to tell it to go to the next `num`.  There is nothing that changes `num` inside the `for` loop.  There's a statement that assigns to `num` **outside** the `for` loop, but that doesn't do you any good as long as you're stuck in the `for` loop.

3)  The `isPrime==true` test is in the wrong place.  It will never succeed, because you've just set it to `false`.  The right place to test `isPrime==true` is after you've checked every divisor.  That means you have to move it **outside** the `for` loop, after the closing curly brace.  (Also, you don't need to say `if (isPrime==true)`; the usual way is just `if (isPrime)`.)

4)  There's one more subtle error that trips up lots of people.  If you have an index that goes through a list, and in the middle of that loop you remove an item from the list, you will miss numbers in the list.  Consider this:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(10, 20, 30, 40));
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    int num = list.get(i);
    if (needToDelete(num)) {
        list.remove(i);
    }
}
```

The first time through the loop, `i` is 0 and `num` is 10.  Say we decide 10 needs to be deleted.  So we remove it.  The list is now [20, 30, 40].  Then we go back, increment `i` to 1, and set `num` to `list.get(1)`--which is now 30!  So we never looked at the element 20.

There are a number of ways to write this differently.  I don't like changing indexes in the middle of a `for` loop, so I'd do this:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < list.size()) {
    num = list.get(i);
    if (needToDelete(num)) {
        list.remove(i);
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Note that I increment `i` only when I don't remove an element from the list.  If I do, `i` stays the same and will now be the index of the next element, since I've removed the earlier one.

Answer (score 0):

```
1) Put boolean isPrime = true; inside for loop. 
2) in for(int o = 2; o < num; ++i) // change ++i to ++o 
3) comment out o=2;  //o=2 and put a break;
4) put nums.remove(i); outside for loop

public static void keepOnlyCompositeNumbers(List<Integer> nums) {
int num = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
    boolean isPrime = true;
    num = nums.get(i);
    {
    for (int o = 2; o < num; ++o) {
        if (num % o == 0) {
        isPrime = false;
        // o=2;
        break;
        }

    }
    if (isPrime == true) {
        nums.remove(i);
    }

    }
}
}
```